# R/exams Moodle schoice question with no points

Tags: moodle, r-exams

I would like to create an `schoice` question in R/exams, via `exams2moodle`, which includes an answer option without points:

```
\begin{answerlist}
  \item Zurich is the capital of Switzerland.
  \item Italian is an official language in Switzerland.
  \item The currency in Switzerland is the Euro.
  \item Switzerland is part of the European Union (EU).
  \item No answer (****** this is a zero points answer****)
\end{answerlist}
```

With these conditions I don't know how to configure \exsolution{0100?}. Thank very much.

PD. Why I need this `schoice` question? In Moodle when one awswer is ticked in `schoice` question,  imply that this question must be answered. Moodle doesn't allow to untick all answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add such an option for "abstention" through the eponymous argument for processing the individual Moodle items. For example for an `mchoice` question (as you list above:

```
exams2moodle("switzerland.Rnw", mchoice = list(abstention = "No answer"))
```

Analogously, you could add `schoice = list(abstention = "Abstention")` etc. In either case this adds an answer option that is associated with zero points:

[image: exams2moodle: abstention]

Comment: Thank you very much. Great R package. Congratulations.

Comment: Please accept the answer by clicking the check mark on the left below the vote count. Then the question is flagged as resolved here on StackOverflow. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry and Thank you.